# Permission denied: Attempt to bind port without permission. FTP

Tags: google-app-engine, ftp, urlconnection

I am trying to retrieve a file from an ftp server with anonymous authentication using java.net.URLConnection.

```
    try {
        url = new URL("ftp://ftp2.sat.gob.mx/Certificados/FEA/000010/000002/02/03/05/00001000000202030500.cer");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
        {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        baos.flush();
        arr = baos.toByteArray();

        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error SAT: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

The file i am trying to get is this, its in an anonymous authentication ftp site:
ftp://ftp2.sat.gob.mx/Certificados/FEA/000010/000002/02/03/05/00001000000202030500.cer

But every time I get this error:
***Permission denied: Attempt to bind port without permission.***

I am using GoogleAppEngine Java 1.7

Any kind of advise is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Java guy, but I suspect you're trying to use "active" FTP, which is likely the default.

Active FTP works by binding to a port on the receiving computer (the client in this case) to which the sending server can connect to send the file; the port number is sent over in the `get` request.  This doesn't work in many environments, e.g. NAT.

The usual solution is to use "passive" mode, which behaves more like HTTP and doesn't require any port binding.  If there's a way in Java to twiddle that connection to use passive mode, it should bypass the permissions issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its not my solution buy it gives me a path to follow.

Comment: Can you share your solution? I have the same issue and i can't connect to the FTP

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a non billing-enabled app, according to [this post](http://googleappengine.blogspot.se/2013/04/app-engine-177-released.html) and [this AppEngine Socket Java API documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/) you just have to enable billing, if you have no budget set the limits to $0.

Comment: My application has billing enabled.